# make - c++: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-std=c++2a’; did you mean ‘-std=c++03’?

Tags: c++, makefile, cmake

I am trying to install https://mmm.humanoids.kit.edu/installation.html. I am using Ubuntu 18.04.6. The instructions require 18.04. I got everything working

```
sudo apt-get install git gitk cmake
sudo apt-get install git-gui cmake-qt-gui
sudo apt-get install doxygen doxygen-gui
sudo apt-get install libeigen3-dev libboost-all-dev
cd ~
git clone https://gitlab.com/mastermotormap/mmmcore.git MMMCore
```

up until the last section

```
cd ~/MMMCore
mkdir build
cd build
cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release ..
```

running cmake returns me

```
kong@kong-Standard:~/MMMCore/build$ cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release ..
-- Using Boost Version 1.65.1
-- Boost version: 1.65.1
-- Found the following Boost libraries:
--   filesystem
--   unit_test_framework
--   system
-- Could NOT find ALGLIB (missing: ALGLIB_LIBRARIES ALGLIB_INCLUDES) 
-- git tag: demo/2021-09-07/r3-0-g605420c
-- current git tag  is not a version
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/kong/MMMCore/build
```

then a `make` returns the error below

```
kong@kong-Standard:~/MMMCore/build$ make
[  1%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/MMMCore.dir/MMM/MathTools.cpp.o
c++: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-std=c++2a’; did you mean ‘-std=c++03’?
CMakeFiles/MMMCore.dir/build.make:62: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/MMMCore.dir/MMM/MathTools.cpp.o' failed
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/MMMCore.dir/MMM/MathTools.cpp.o] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:67: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/MMMCore.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/MMMCore.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:162: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Below is the relevant portion of the CMakeLists.txt. I tried googling for anything related to the message `unrecognized command line option ‘-std=c++2a’; did you mean ‘-std=c++03’` but could not find any help with the same version `c++2a`. Could someone kindly help me please as I have 0 experience with Cmake.

```
###########################################################
#### Compiler configuration                            ####
###########################################################

set(CMAKE_POSITION_INDEPENDENT_CODE ON) # enable -fPIC

if(MSVC)
    set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} /W4 /MP")
elseif(CMAKE_COMPILER_IS_GNUCC OR CMAKE_COMPILER_IS_GNUCXX)
    # cmake 3.10 does not understand c++2a, so we tell it we will handle the standard flag
    set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_DEFAULT)
    add_definitions(-std=c++2a)
    set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -Wall -Wno-long-long -pedantic")
endif()

add_compile_options(-Werror)
```

EDIT:

This is the compiler I have

```
kong@kong-Standard:~/MMMCore/build$ gcc --version
gcc (Ubuntu 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04) 7.5.0
Copyright (C) 2017 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

Comment: Version of compiler you have installed is too old and lack any support for C++20

Comment: @Jorengarenar did you mean the cmake compiler? Because my cmake version is 3.10.2-1ubuntu2.18.04.2, which is the version required in the instructions

Comment: No, CMake is a build system generation tool - it creates e.g. Makefiles, which in turn tell compiler what to do. Compiler is a program like GCC, Clang or MSVC - it translates your code to format understandable by computer

Comment: @Jorengarenar thank you very much, my compiler version (gcc --version) is 7.5.0 so I need to upgrade it